# Missing click-action key for webpush payload on message sent via FCM HTTPv1

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending a web push notification to a client browser via FCM HTTPv1. I would like to add an action when the notification is clicked.

I know one can do it with the FCM Admin SDK: 'clickAction' is one of the key of [admin.messaging.NotificationMessagePayload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.NotificationMessagePayload).

But [WebPushNotification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#webpushnotification) from the message payload sent via FCM HTTPv1 only includes 'title', 'body' and 'icon'.

How to add actions to web push notifications sent via FCM HTTPv1?

Comment: Did some digging, looks like support for `click` parameter in a `WebpushNotification` is not yet available. The v1 protocol is still fairly new and it might be possible that Firebase will release a support soon.

Comment: I replied here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177428/http-v1-api-click-action-for-webpush-notification/51268298#51268298