# How should I open links on web-push notification click - service worker or"click_action"?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm currently working on integrating [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) for push notifications in my web application.
I have a question regarding the behavior of clicks on web-push notifications and how to define this behavior and gather information and analytics.

My question is some what similar to these questions:

- [click_action attribute for web push notification through FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50148266/click-action-attribute-for-web-push-notification-through-fcm)
- [Missing click-action key for webpush payload on message sent via FCM HTTPv1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457799/missing-click-action-key-for-webpush-payload-on-message-sent-via-fcm-httpv1)
- [HTTP v1 API: "click_action" for webpush notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177428/http-v1-api-click-action-for-webpush-notification/)

However, there are some differences.

The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#setting_notification_options_in_the_send_request) doesn't explicitly address whether to use `click_action` or `service worker` to handle click behavior.

I have read the [Message Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) article, which mentions two types of messages:

- Notification messages
- Data messages

But I didn't understand the difference between them.

Let's say I want end-users who receive notifications from my backend systems to be directed to `example.com` when they click on the notification.

I've achieved this using a service worker:

```
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", (event) => {
    const notificationData = event.notification.data;
    const targetPageUrl = notificationData && notificationData.tracking
    return clients.openWindow(targetPageUrl);
 }
```

As you can see, it parses the data field in the notification payload and then opens the URL.

Here's the payload I'm using:

```
"webpush": {
"notification": {
  "title": "This is a test notification",
  "body": "test test test",
  "data": {
    "tracking": "https://example.com?source=data_field"
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "action": "yes",
      "title": "Enter to the site",
    },
    {
      "action": "no",
      "title": "Ignore",
    }
  ],
},
"fcm_options": {
  "link": "https://example.com?source=fcm_options"
 }
}
```

However, if I understand correctly from the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#setting_notification_options_in_the_send_request), I shouldn't need to do this. I can implement the URL in the payload as part of `fcm_options.link`, and this should handle the click operation without the need to handle it in the service worker.

But for some reason, it doesn't work for me - nothing happens when I click on the notification (if I remove the handling of the `onclick` from the service worker).

I would appreciate some assistance and clarification on how to handle the click behavior of web-push notifications by using the `fcm_options.link` field and without the need of the `service worker`.