# HTTP v1 API: "click_action" for webpush notification

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Documentation in FCM focuses heavily on Android/iOS and my lowly `webpush` self is struggling with `click_action`.

`click_action` was a key which could be used in older APIs and appears to be no longer available for `webpush`.

The only specific reference to this is in this blog post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/11/whats-new-with-fcm-customizing-messages.html which again focuses on iOS and Android.

I am looking for clarity that `click_action` is indeed now unsupported for `webpush` messages.

Comment: See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42300152/4625829). Although this is for Legacy. I don't see any reason why they'd remove this in v1

Comment: If it is supported, it's not documented as a [WebpushConfig](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#webpushconfig) option, config header property, or [WebpushNotification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#WebpushNotification) option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click_action works for me but I think it is not documented yet.

I added it in webpush -> notification -> click_action.

Edit : a new option is available in HTTP v1 API.

Comment: And you're using `FCM HTTP v1 API`?

Comment: Sure. Because legacy doesn't authorize all parameters for notifications.

Comment: I can confirm `click_action` does not work in `FCM HTTP v1`. Specifically: "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"click_action\" at 'message.webpush': Cannot find field.

Comment: It's work very well for me. I'm looking for why it's ok for me et not for you.
{"message":{"topic":"push-test","webpush":{"notification":{"actions":[],"tag":123456,"title":"Titre de test","body":"Un contenu de notification","image":".\/images\/icon.png","badge":".\/images\/badge.png","icon":".\/images\/icon256.png","vibrate":[50,200,50],"click_action":"\/"},"data":{"time":"1531396372"},"headers":{"TTL":"60"}}}}

Comment: Edit: hmm, I've tested using your code and it's working well. Will mark your answer as correct when I can

Comment: Add click_action in message.webpush.notification.

Answer (score 2):

Use your `WebpushNotification.Builder` object and call the `putCustomData()` method with `click_action` as the key and your `click_action` URL as the value.

With the Java Firebase Admin SDK, it looks like this:

```
wpnb.putCustomData("click_action", "<your_url_here>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include whatever key=>value pairs you want within the data field of your Web Push payload.

Register a notificationclick event listener in your service worker and these data values are available within the event triggered when your notification is clicked. Access your data, then execute your desired click action.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but `FCM HTTP v1 API` has no documentation on the use of service workers as far as I can see.

Comment: It's documentation for the FCM API so I wouldn't expect it to cover service workers. They document different types of notifications you can create here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#Notification and there are numberous websites which explain the service workers api. Using the Web Push format gives you many more options for customising your notifications as well as tracking user interactions with them

Answer (score -2):

Confirmed by multiple sources. `click_action` is not currently supported for WebPush in HTTP V1 on Firebase Cloud Messaging. Sad!

Comment: Why not put it in a separate, arbitrary data array?